# Is it possible to query the Active Directory from Azure SQL

Tags: sql-server, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, adsi

I am migrating from an older version of Microsoft SQL to Azure SQL.  The existing SQL Server stored procedures use OPENQUERY and a linked ADSI server to retrieve user information directly from the Active Directory.

Is this possible in Azure SQL?

Comment: If you mean to query your Domain Server, then no. An Azure SQL Database isn't going to be part of your domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure SQL Database only allows to query another Azure SQL Database (remote) or Azure Synapse Analytics databases using elastic queries. All other SQL and non-SQL sources are not allowed.

Azure Managed Instance uses a private VNET and supports linked servers to a limited number of targets. Supported targets: SQL Server and SQL Database. Not supported targets: Active Directory, files, Excel, Oracle, MySQL, Analysis Services, and other RDBMS.

Azure SQL Database would have no way to communicate with your on-premises servers since it does not uses private VNETs as Managed Instance does.

If you rely heavily on this you should discard all Azure SQL (PaaS) options and go for a SQL Server Azure VM.